# Retrieve phone number from SQL Server database into Label Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sms, twilio

I have a problem with code that has **label** that needs to store **phone number** taken from a SQL Server database. I need to use that **number** to send a message to **it**.

(I think a problem in + sign in Dialing Code)

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
connection.Open();           


SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("select * from DB where Phone=@phone", connection);
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Label.Text);


string phone = Label1.Text;
Label1.Visible = true;

string AccountSid = "MyCode";
string AuthToken = "MYCODE";

var message = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
var sms = message.SendMessage("MyNumber", phone, "Message Sent.", "");
Console.WriteLine(sms.Sid);
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I don' understand. What is your question exactly? And you don't use `com1` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @SonerGönül No I've used com1 to addWithValue Parameter statement. However, my question is: how to take number from database (SQL) and store that number in Label to use it in my C# code.

Comment: @AviGinsburg No I've used com1 to addWithValue Parameter statement. However, my question is: how to take number from database (SQL) and store that number in Label to use it in my C# code.

Comment: SqlDataReader dr = com1.ExecucteDataReader();

Comment: If you want to store the number though youll want to change the sql to an insert statement

Comment: @Ewan No, I mean by storing is to store the number that in the database in label variable

Comment: Kindly take a look on my post below. It might be the one you're looking to?

Comment: If Label1.Text = phone number , why you want to get it again from db?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the datareader on your code. something like below.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
connection.Open();           

string phone = Label1.Text;
Label1.Visible = true;

SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("select * from DB where Phone=@phone", connection);
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Label.Text);
SqlDataReader reader = com1.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows()) 
{
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      phone = reader["ColumnName"].toString();
   }
}   

string AccountSid = "MyCode";
string AuthToken = "MYCODE";

var message = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
var sms = message.SendMessage("MyNumber", phone, "Message Sent.", "");
Console.WriteLine(sms.Sid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of inserting to a database

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Transactions;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    public class User {
        public String Username {get;set;}
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IRepository
    {
        void AddUser(User user);
        bool IsUsernamefree(User user);
    }

    public class RepositorySql : IRepository
    {
        private string constr;
        public RepositorySql(string connstr)
        {
            this.constr = connstr;

        }
        public void AddUser(User user)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into phoneNumbers (phone) values (@phone)", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", user.Phone);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class UserRegistrationViewModel
    {
        private IRepository rep;

        public string ErrorMessage {get;set;}

        public UserRegistrationViewModel(IRepository rep)
        {
            this.rep = rep;
        }

        public bool AddUser(User user)
        {
            using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
            {
                rep.AddUser(user);
                ErrorMessage = "";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```